# how to send JSON data from android to IP address for example 192.168.2.1:80?

Tags: android, json, network-programming

I Have a json data  in android app and want to pass it to some ip address with port no 80. With code below i am able to send String data with no problems, however when i try to pass the json data it starts giving me error
 "Illegal character in query at index 22: http://192.168.x.x:80/{"MainUi":{"IpAddress":"192.168.x.x","Message":"Nov",.....}

```
private class TaskRun extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

            String server;

            TaskEsp(String server) {
                this.server = server;
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                String val = params[0];
                System.out.print(val);
                final String p = "http://" + server + "/" + val;

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Log.v(TAG, p);
                    }
                });


                String serverResponse = "";
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                try {
                    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet();
                    httpGet.setURI(new URI(p));
                    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpGet);
                    InputStream inputStream = null;
                    inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                    serverResponse = bufferedReader.readLine();

                    inputStream.close();
                } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    serverResponse = e.getMessage();
                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    serverResponse = e.getMessage();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    serverResponse = e.getMessage();
                }

                return serverResponse;
            }
```

Comment: Json as url parameter????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all sending Json data in Url is a bad practice. Instead, as a good practice, you should send data into the body of the HTTP POST request or as url parameters in HTTP GET request.

Your problem happens because you writing unsafe characters (curly brackts) in the Url.

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();
jsonObj.put("name", "Jhon");

HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            try {
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet();
    httpGet.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    httpGet.setHeader("Accept-Encoding", "compress, gzip");
    httpGet.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    http.setURI(URI.create(p));

    StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(jsonObj.toString(), HTTP.UTF_8);
    entity.setContentEncoding(HTTP.UTF_8);
    entity.setContentType("application/json");

    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

    InputStream inputStream = AndroidHttpClient.getUngzippedContent(httpResponse.getEntity());

    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    serverResponse = bufferedReader.readLine();

    inputStream.close();
} catch (URISyntaxException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    serverResponse = e.getMessage();
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    serverResponse = e.getMessage();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    serverResponse = e.getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you every one  this is how i implemented the program.

The below code  explain's how i used Json data and send it as an string.

```
public void writeJSON() {
        JSONObject LedActivity = new JSONObject();
        JSONObject JsonRawData = new JSONObject();
        try {
            LedActivity.put("Type of Light", Spinnerposition); //gets the current spinnerPosition
            LedActivity.put("Light Brightness", Bit); 
            LedActivity.put("TimeDelay",TimePosition); //gets  the seekbar position
            LedActivity.put("Blink", isBlinkTurned); // gets the state of button
            LedActivity.put("Fade", isFadeTurned);

            JsonRawData.put("LedActivity", LedActivity);
            jsonLight = JsonRawData.toString(1);
            System.out.println(jsonLight);
            sendPost(jsonLight); // send the json light string data to send post function
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

The below code send the data in string to any ip address on port 80.

```
public static void sendPost(final String postData) {
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                URL url = new URL("http://" + IpSelected + ":80");
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                conn.setDoInput(true);

                DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
                // os.writeBytes(URLEncoder.encode(postData, "UTF-8"));
                os.writeBytes(postData);

                os.flush();
                os.close();

                Log.i("STATUS", String.valueOf(conn.getResponseCode()));
                Log.i("MSG", conn.getResponseMessage());

                conn.disconnect();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    thread.start();
}
```